# Отсутствие перевода для редактирования краткого описания метки в разделе Активность -> Сообщения

Tags: дефект, локализация, описание-метки

В разделе `Активность/Сообщения` отсутствует перевод для редактирования краткого описания метки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Об этом есть [бага на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292499/339911). Лучше перед публикацией посмотреть в traducir, если там нет строки, то посмотреть на MSE. Ну и публиковать сразу на MSE, т.к. отсутствие строк для перевода распространяется на ВСЕ неаглоязычные сайты, а стало быть, следует репортить на MSE, а не на локальной Мете.